# Windows permissions. Deny changes by user, allow changes by program

Tags: windows, permissions

Here is a simplified scenario of what I need to do:

On Windows Server 2008, I need to allow a program (which is run by an unprivileged user) to modify a file, do whatever it needs to do, but not allow the user to change anything in a file directly (or even view it).

I remember doing this on Linux, you could change permissions on an executable file (something like this: `chmod g+s program`) and then the program would run with group privileges (ex. the group which is allowed to change the file). How can I accomplish this, maybe there's a better solution?

By the way, the program is on a Windows share (mapped drive)

Comment: This can be done by running the program as another user.  Of course the current iteration of this question seems all to similar to a software recommendation ( of course a program isn't even required in a case like this ) which is the only reason I am not voting to close.

Comment: But how can I restrict people from logging in using this another user if they know credentials already? By no means I am asking for software recommendation :)

Comment: You can't.  I suspect you should be able to create a .bat file the contains the password for the user and contains the command, but place the permission on it, that prevents somebody from editing the file but still allowing them to execute it.

Comment: So, you mean, I create an unprivileged user for them to login and a privileged user which I use inside a batch script, which they can't read and only execute?

Comment: You already have a normal unprivileged user.  I am saying you need to run the program as the privileged user.